# VBA // set variable in stored procedure (mssql) // ADODB

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, ado

I have a stored procedure on a mssql server including a local variable name "path" is it possible to set this variable out of vba? 
In vba I get a path to a file, this path needs the stored procedure to finish some work... 
How can I set this variable?

Thx!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run a Stored procedure with parameters from Excel VBA string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31986552/how-do-i-run-a-stored-procedure-with-parameters-from-excel-vba-string)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can run a Sproc from VBA.

```
Sub RunSP()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset

Set con = New Connection
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.[Ten Most Expensive Products]")
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close
End Sub
```

Are you saying that the path is in a call?  If you want the value of a cell, just reference it.

```
ThePath = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. It's very important to include ' ' in the parameter/variable.

Example:

```
@qry = "procedure-Name" @ PATH <- in this Variable you must include ' ' to set the Parameter in the stored procedure - blank is not necessary!!
```

then:

```
cn.Execute qry
```