# VBA Excel - SQL "execute" method triggered query timeout expired

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

This is not the same issue as in [Excel VBA: ODBC SQL Server driver query timeout expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44708549/excel-vba-odbc-sql-server-driver-query-timeout-expired)

The bellow code line triggered:

> [Microsoft] [ODBC SQL Server Driver] Query timeout expired`  after 30 seconds.

Code:

```
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection 
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set rs = conn.Execute(WOString)
```

My question is, how can I extend the time for timeout on `Execute` method? `Application.ODBCTimeout = 100` or `conn.CommandTimeout = 100` has no effect.

If it has any importance I use standard connection string (but the connection works without any problem):

```
Driver={SQL Server};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

Comment: Assuming you are using ADO, the query timeout (in seconds) can be specified via the connection [`CommandTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/commandtimeout-property-ado?view=sql-server-ver15) property. For example, `conn.CommandTimeout = 300`. In the case of a command object, set the property on the command since it's not inherited from the connection.

Comment: I tried but is not working

Comment: Amusingly, however, that is exactly what the answer is in the question the OP says this isn't a duplicate of, @DanGuzman , so I *assume* the OP has tried that and it doesn't work? Perhaps that aren't using ADO?

Comment: My ADO assumption is incorrect if it doesn't work. An important detail missing from the question is what object type  `conn` actually is. Add the `DIM conn` statement for clarity.

Comment: `Dim conn As ADODB.Connection`
`Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: If you increase the `conn.CommandTimeout`: When does the error appear - after 30s or after the time you provided? Are you sure your query is correct and can be executed in that time?

Comment: @FunThomas After 30 seconds (as default).

Comment: Other queries works because doesn't require more then 30 seconds for execution. Unfortunately this query needs more than 30 s.

Comment: Though, obviously, stopping the timeout after 30s is an obvious fix, have you considered seeing if you can bring the execution down of the query instead?

Comment: In Access you can change the query properties, but in Excel how can be done?

Comment: @Larnu The query cannot be more optimized than that :( I admit it is huge (4383 characters) because requires a lot of table joins

Comment: Have you considered using a ADODB.Command object to execute WOString instead of assuming that ADODB.Connection.Execute() is doing the right thing? ref: [Creating and Executing a Simple Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: That isn't really a lot of characters. @BOB . I have a SP that is over 50,000 characters long, and it runs in a couple of seconds... Characters aren't the biggest contribution to how quick a query performs; they are *way* down at the bottom.

Comment: @Larnu I know that the length of the query doesn't count. Anyway in SQL server the execution time is less then 1 sec.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I tried now and I received the same timeout error

Comment: That doesn't sound right then, @BOB , if the query takes less than a second when running the query in your preferred IDE, if should not be taking over 30 seconds in VBA; sounds like we're missing something here.

Comment: Once I had over 1 minute in SQL server and that's why I think if I can extend the timeout in VBA can solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

CommandTimeout works fine.  See repro:

----------test.vbs-----------

```
Sub testSub()
    Dim cn 'As Object
    Dim cnStr 'As String
    cnStr = "DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=localhost;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=true"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = cnStr
        .ConnectionTimeout = 10
        .CommandTimeout = 100
        .Open
        If .State = 1 Then
            .Execute("waitfor delay '00:01:00'")
        End If
    End With
End Sub

testSub()
```

then run

```
 cscript .\test.vbs
```