# VBA to run 500 line query won't run

Tags: sql, excel, vba, line-breaks

I am trying to write vba code that includes running a query and pasting the results into excel. I have done this many times in the past, but all with just one line queries. I am trying to do it with a 500 line query and I am getting errors due to the line breaks

I have already tried doing line breaks and carriage returns, but I am obviously way over the line break maximum

previously my final code would look like

```
finalquery = " SELECT * from tbl1 with (nolock) where column1 (" & finalresult & ")"
```

Now I have a really long query and iIwant to do this with and am not sure how to

Comment: You can't use more than 24 line continue signs " _" in the VBA editor, but you can easily concatenate you statement. Anyhow, depending on your datasource, it seems to me that it's better to implement the logic on database side (View, Query, Stored proc...)

Comment: This looks like a job for a parameterized stored procedure. Especially if any of the values you're concatenating come from user inputs. [Meet Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that I have ever seen a query that long and think you could run into trouble!  But you could do...

```
finalquery +"This is the first " & _
            "part of my query "
finalquery = finalquery  & "This is the second " & _
            "part of my query"
finalquery = finalquery  & "This is the third" & _
            "part of my query"
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

There's a maximum number of *physical lines* a VBA *logical line* of code can span; that maximum is around 20, but generally speaking you should avoid such long instructions in code.

The SQL statement is a string literal, and thus can't easily be debugged or maintained.

Make a [parameterized stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31986552/1188513) on the server, and you won't need to concatenate anything.

Comment: This is not a possibility due to permission issues. Are there any other work arounds?

Comment: Yes, fix the permissions and get a DBA to write the procedure if you have to. 500-liner SQL in a string literal is pure madness.

Comment: @UserX Alternatively, have the script in a separate text file, and load the text into a string at run-time. The last thing you want is to have that mess in your code.

Comment: this could work, I think i could save the text file on a shared drive and then maybe call it? so it will run for anyone using the file

Comment: If there's a DBA responsible for these permissions, talk to them first. They're MUCH more likely to prefer a server-side stored procedure over an arbitrary concatenated client-side script. Then there's the whole security issue with the parameterization, which is completely taken care of with a stored procedure. Pretty sure they'll be happy to turn your script into an actual stored procedure and grant your login access to execute it if you explain that the alternative is to have that script loaded from some network share, or hard-coded in some VBA code.